# Change the font displayed as you type QTable

Tags: c++, qt

The font in the cells is large

[image: foto1]

but the font is small when you enter it

[image: foto2].

Is it possible to configure the font when entering text without using "qt designer" so that you can change it dynamically

Comment: Please try to mention language or framework you are working on.

Comment: @HaSeeBMiR that's what the tags are for: C++ and Qt

Comment: but try to include in question also it would help in reading .

Comment: @HaSeeBMiR no, it is enough with the tags. Bye

Comment: Its a matter of opinion as you say.

Comment: @HaseeBMir No, it's a matter of to keep text clean from noise. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ui->tableWidget->QWidget::setFont(QFont("Times",89,QFont::Bold));`

Answer (score 0):

You can Use .setFont(QFont("Arial", 32))

Comment: My reputation is less than 50 so cant comment, You can set font for an entire Qtable with above method.

Comment: [video](https://yadi.sk/i/pPkarHmbNB7Tqg)  when I enter a number, the font is small, but after I enter the font becomes the way I set it. can I make the text larger when I enter it

Comment: _My reputation is less than 50 so cant comment_ then probably there is a reason for it to be like that. Do not try to overcome the rules.

Comment: [video](https://yadi.sk/i/jscPY4v_IC7E-g) [screenshot](https://yadi.sk/i/l9abZQHUiHvhEA) if you change the font in the designer window, the following happens. how to configure this font.